# Bash History Search

Tags: bash, command-history, search

Is there a way to search bash history similar to zsh history search with percol?
as shown at [percol](https://github.com/mooz/percol#zsh-history-search)'s github page. Specifically I want to be able to navigate the history interactively using a terminal UI (TUI).

[image: example of a percol history search]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A few seconds on Google turned this up
https://github.com/dvorka/hstr.

> Bash and Zsh shell history suggest box - easily view, navigate, search and manage your command history. Easily view, navigate, search and use your command history with shell history suggest box for Bash and Zsh.

[image: ss of hstr]

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for. Thank you!